# How to create a producer/consumer thread schema?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have multiple workerThreads and a producerThread. When I run below code Worker threads are runnig rarely. I am getting an input like;

```
workToDo Size: 1
workToDo Size: 2
...
workToDo Size: 514
91 removed  //First remove output
```

workToDo list is just increasing. Is there any way to decrease run interval of worker threads? I think I am doing something wrong here.

My main method;

```
WorkerThread workerThread = new WorkerThread();
WorkerThread workerThread2 = new WorkerThread();
WorkerThread workerThread3 = new WorkerThread();
ProducerThread producerThread = new ProducerThread();
workerThread.producerThread = producerThread;
workerThread2.producerThread = producerThread;
workerThread3.producerThread = producerThread;
producerThread.start();
workerThread.start();
workerThread2.start();
workerThread3.start();
```

WorkerThread;

```
public class WorkerThread extends Thread {

  ProducerThread producerThread;

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
        synchronized (producerThread) {
            try {
                producerThread.wait();
                System.out.println(producerThread.workToDo.remove(0) + " removed");
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

ProducerThread;

```
public class ProducerThread extends Thread {

  List<Integer> workToDo = new ArrayList();

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
        synchronized (this) {
            workToDo.add((int)(Math.random() * 100));
            System.out.println("workToDo Size: " + workToDo.size());
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a BlockingConcurrentQueue where your producer puts tasks.  Then have your worker threads grab tasks from this queue.

Comment: There are several things wrong here, but most pertinently your producer thread probably reacquires the monitor before the other threads have a chance to wake up. With a `BlockingQueue` you can get rid of all the complexity and most obvious sources of errors.

Comment: All of your workers just sit there waiting for Producer to stop, getting anything done only rarely when the monitor is somehow free. Which basically only happens if they can get in there between where lines `while(true)` and `synchronized(this)` executed (those are in producer implementation). You should seek for more expressive synchronization primitives, supposedly some `java.util.concurrent.Condition`, which workers wait on and producers signal on.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I'm not even sure the optimiser can't deduce that there is no "in between", and just decide that the whole loop is within the synchronized block.

Comment: @biziclop, well, since there is a `"removed"` statement in log, the whole loop clearly not optimized (or not-yet-optimized) into synchronized block (I'm not actually sure that this that would be a valid optimization, actually, since that changes semantics - the loop is supposed to have punctured synchronization there, not continuous). This implementation just makes it very unlikely that any consumers can get a hold of a monitor is all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> workToDo list is just increasing. Is there any way to decrease run interval of worker threads? I think I am doing something wrong here.

Without seeing more code, it's hard to fully answer but this seems like a typical problem when your producer thread(s) can produce work faster than the consumers can process them.  You should be using a *bounded* `BlockingQueue` so that you only queue up a certain number of requests and not fill memory with them.

You should consider using the [`ExecutorService` classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) with a bounded queue.  For example:

```
// start a thread pool with 3 worker threads and a queue of 100
ExecutorService threadPool =
      new ThreadPoolExecutor(3, 3, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                             new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100));
// to get the producer to _block_ instead of rejecting the job you need a handler
threadPool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
     public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
         // this will cause the producer to block until there is room in queue
         executor.getQueue().add(r);
     }
});
```

Your producer thread, which could also be a job running in the threadPool if you increase the thread count to 4, would then just submit `Runnable` jobs to your thread pool to be worked on by the 3 worker threads.  If the 3 are busy then it will queue up the requests in the `ArrayBlockingQueue`.  Once 100 (feel free to change that number) jobs are queued, the producer will block until another job completes.

Using the `ExecutorService` and `BlockingQueue` means that all of the waiting and notify logic which is hard to get right is taken care of for you.